# IBM WebSphere MQ V7 MQQueue setTargetClient MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ deprecated

Tags: ibm-mq

Trying to migrate from IBM WebSphere MQ V6 to V7.

One of the line that we have is

```
((com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueue) queue).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
```

`JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ` shows up as deprecated in V7.

What is the proper replacement for the line? I looked around for a while, but couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please see the *[WebSphere MQ Using Java](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/uj10120_.htm)* manual.  In particular, look in the *[Properties of Objects](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10910_.htm)* section and scroll down to Table 3.  Next, find the entry in Table 3 for `TARGCLIENT`.  In the far right column are the values for each of the setter methods.  In this case, the values for the `setTargetClient` method are:

- `WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_JMS_COMPLIANT`
- `WMQConstants.WMQ_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ`

In the same manual, it is a good idea to review the installation and verification for the new version.   Among other things, the classes have been repackaged and so the `[CLASSPATH][3]` requirements have changed.

Since you are migrating from V6 to V7, another good reference is the *[WebSphere MQ Migration](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi10120_.htm)* manual.  In particular, please see the section entitled *[Java and JMS considerations](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzao.doc/mi11380_.htm)* for additional advice for migrating applications.  Other sections in this manual will be helpful as well.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that Fix Pack 7.0.1.5 has just been released and contains several Java/JMS related fixes.  If you are running an earlier version of V7, it would be an extremely good idea to download and apply the maintenance.  There are two ways to do this.  First, the WMQ client download always has the latest version.  You can always download it and install over top of a previous client.  It is available as a free download at [SupportPac MQC7](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC7).  Alternatively, you can download the Fix Pack from the [Recommended Fixes](http://ibm.co/oFdVGH) page.  This is supplied as a platform-specific upgrade to the existing install, for example an EXE on Windows, an RPM for Linux, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In case you didn't feel like reading through the documents.  In v7 you need to uncheck the box labeled "Append RFH version 2 headers to messages sent to this destination" under the advanced properties of the queue on the Admin Console.  This tells it that you are sending to an MQ and not JMS Queue.